# EMR activity stuck in Waiting_For_Runner state

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am creating a data pipeline to export dynamoDB table to S3 bucket.I used the standard template to use for this in data pipeline console. I ha verified that the runsOn field is set to the name of EMR cluster to be started. However, The EMR activity status is still as Waiting_For_Runner...Any ideas why is this so??

Thanks!!!

Comment: solved the issue.. authorization problem :(

Comment: How did you fix this authorization issue?

Answer (score 1):

Waiting_For_Runner means datatpipeline is trying to connect to EMR.

Few reasons you can check:

1. IAM permissions between EMR and Data pipeline(Roles). Here's [a link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html)!
2. Check Task runner is running or not on master instance
   `$ps -ef | grep workerGroup` (Master Instance)
3. Check --workgroup name in EMR(you can see in Task runner process) and compare it with the name of workgroup in datapipeline.

Comment: What are the IAM permissions supposed to be?

Comment: @AidanConnelly you can refer below AWS Doc link for IAM stuff:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html